# How do I install TypeScript?

Tags: installation, typescript

I have version 0.9.1.1. So I ran the following:

```
C:\test>npm install -g typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.0.0.tgz
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
typescript@1.0.0 C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript
```

But when I run tsc I get:

```
C:\test>tsc
Version 0.9.1.1
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ..]
```

What else do I need to do to install the latest version?

**Update:**

```
C:\test>where tsc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.js
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

tsc.exe is 0.9.1.1 and tsc.cmd is 1.0.0.0

I then removed the VisualStudio 0.9.1.1 AddIn and it's now all good - just tsc.cmd and that's 1.0.0.0

Thank you all!

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I am trying to install the typescript compiler. I think installing a compiler counts as programming.

Comment: Yes, you are right, problems with a compiler are on topic here, but it looks this question is just about typing a command on the command line.

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't understand before.

Comment: What is the result of running "where tsc" ?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh - thank you, that found the problem (see above update).

Comment: @LorenzMeyer - not a problem, I sometimes don't understand questions posted here at first either.

Comment: Heh, this question will rake in the points now that the Angular.io quickstart links here :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What else do I need to do to install the latest version?

It is because you probably (almost definitely) have TypeScript plugin for visual studio installed. You can uninstall that from *Control Panel*. Then the typescript you installed from *npm* will be the default one on the command line.

Alternatively you can get the latest TypeScript from Visual Studio 2012 plugin from here : http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download (For VS 2013 it is bundled as a part of VS 2013 update 2 RC)

Comment: if you don't want to uninstall VS, explicitly use `tsc` which is installed via npm will also work :)

Answer (score 8):

Removing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\` from **`PATH`** environment variable did the job for me.

`Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> system variables -> PATH`

Answer (score 5):

**TypeScript Version Issues and How to Update using NPM**

I had a similar issue, whereby I downloaded both 1.4 and the beta version of 1.5, when I ran the command tsc -v, it kept returning version 1.0...

When I went to the folder indicated above, I saw three versions 1.0, 1.4. and 1.5. deleting 1.0 allowed 1.5 to run...

[image]

Comment: I ran across this again today, except I was using NPM to put typescript into local development folder.  It bit me because Visual Studio uses the folder above and not any local or global NPM folders!  In today's issue, I simply needed to put in the 2.1 version and it worked, but I removed the other two as I didn't have any dual-maintenance work going on.  Turns out that there's a way to tell VS what version to use using json.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just change the "Path" environment parameter from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\`**1.0**`"` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\`**1.5**`"`, then it's all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this make sure you have typed in

```
npm install -g typescript
```

I went to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\

And deleted the 1.0 folder
After doing that I did tsc -v on the command line and it finally returned 2.7 as shown below.

```
PS c:\users\username> tsc -v
Version 2.7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

**How Do I install TypeScript?**

First we have to install the node.js. Download it from this location

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

and run the .msi installer, to check whether it is installed or not just use below command in command prompt

**node -v**

It would display the version of the installed node.js.

Then use below command in command prompt to install the TypeScript

**npm install -g typescript**

Answer (score -1):

You installed it correctly but while calling the compiler you just need to mention the path of the source file,something like this:

```
C:\test>tsc example.ts
```

Check [this link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/tutorial) for more information

Comment: But it lists that it is version 0.9.1.1 while I installed version 1.0.0. So it's still using the previous version.